# Android TvView: change aspect ratio

Tags: android, aspect-ratio

I'm using `android.media.tv.TvView` in my android tv app to view live TV in a small space (fragment) within in the app.

While watching live cricket, clients are complaining that they can't see the score which is at the bottom. How can I adjust the aspect ratio or scale the content of `TvView` to solve this issue?

my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.media.tv.TvView
        android:id="@+id/tvView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment code for initializing TvView:

```
TvInputManager mTvInputManager = (TvInputManager) requireContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TV_INPUT_SERVICE);
List<TvInputInfo> inputs = mTvInputManager.getTvInputList();

List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
for (TvInputInfo info : inputs) {
     if (info.getType() == type) {
         String id = info.getParentId() != null ? info.getParentId() : info.getId();
         if (!ids.contains(id)) {
             ids.add(id);
         }
     }
}
int idx = viewModel.deviceDetails.getSettings().getOtherDetails().getPort() - 1;
String id = ids.get(idx);
tvView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
tvView.tune(id, TvContract.buildChannelUriForPassthroughInput(id));
```

Comment: Any screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Seems like the `TvView` would be bound by the width and height of the `FrameLayout` which you've set to `match_parent`. You've not given us enough information to infer the width and height of the `FrameLayout`'s parent but I suspect that's where your answer is and you can set an aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

The android.media.tv.TvView class does not provide a direct method to set the aspect ratio. However, you can achieve the desired aspect ratio by adjusting the layout parameters of the TvView within its parent layout.

Here's an example of how you can set the aspect ratio for a TvView programmatically:

```
TvView tvView = findViewById(R.id.tv_view); // Assuming you have a TvView in your layout

// Calculate the desired aspect ratio (e.g., 16:9)
float aspectRatio = 16f / 9f;

// Get the parent layout of the TvView
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) tvView.getLayoutParams();

// Calculate the new width and height based on the aspect ratio
int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = (int) (width / aspectRatio);

// Set the new width and height
layoutParams.width = width;
layoutParams.height = height;

// Apply the new layout parameters to the TvView
tvView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

In this example, we calculate the new width and height for the TvView based on the desired aspect ratio (16:9 in this case). We assume the width of the TvView should match the width of the device's screen. Then, we calculate the height by dividing the width by the aspect ratio. Finally, we update the layout parameters of the TvView to reflect the new width and height.

By adjusting the layout parameters of the TvView dynamically, you can achieve the desired aspect ratio for the TvView on Android.